# What is "rolling back"?

Tags: support, editing, rollback

I have seen the gaming.SE Badge "Cleanup: First Rollback" and searched for it but couldn't find anything on to what it refers.

What does this mean? How do I *roll back* (presumably a question, an answer or a comment)?

Comment: Alright! Fight to the death between [Arda Xi](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/what-is-rolling-back/1413#1413) and [Ivo Flipse](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/what-is-rolling-back/1414#1414) to include [some](http://i.imgur.com/2J8cW.png) [screenshots](http://i.imgur.com/UkjFI.png) of how it is actually done! Bonus points for an extra screenshot detailing how to do it amidst actively editing a question.

Comment: @Grace How's this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rolling back a question or an answer is an option while editing it. Basically you restore (roll back to) a previous version of a post. You do this when, for example, someone abused the edit function on a question, or made an edit to your post you don't agree with.

I took on Grace's challenge, but I upped the ante with a [screencast](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26426/rollback.htm) [or two](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26426/gracenitpicking.htm).

Comment: I was somewhat hoping for how to trigger the spawn conditions for [this unique beast](http://i.imgur.com/m1CBz.png "Happy Hunting!"). But... Ivo didn't put up a fight, and you did go beyond expectations, so I'd say the round goes to you. Enjoy 10000 bonus points! ♪

Comment: @Grace Is this better?

Comment: Haha! Very nice, very nice! It's a useful thing to know, since that's how you do rollbacks with edit summaries. Thanks~ ♪

Comment: @Grace I'd happily take on the challenge if I could have edited **his** post, sadly I'm not awesome enough on Gaming...

Comment: Arbitrary comment about lack of freehand circles in the demo.

Comment: @TheQ Would've, but I wasn't going to edit every screenshot by hand.

Comment: Drats. Probably for the best that we don't migrate the original meta memes over here anyway.

Comment: And by the way +1 for the awesome presentation, Arda :)

Answer (score 4):

It means that if I edit your post and you disagree with my edit, there is an option to rollback the edit.

This only applies to questions and answers